# Crosshair on the wrong location on the Video screen after 'fitInView' call

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

This question is relate to this:
[Video size not fill in QGraphicsView window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124350/video-size-not-fill-in-qgraphicsview-window?noredirect=1#comment102637924_58124350)

I tried to use 'scene->addLine(...)' to add a 'red' line to the screen. But, it was far off after 'fitInView' call. In the beginning, the crosshair was in the correct place, the middle of the screen. But, it totally went off the screen when the vide started (after 'fitInView' Lambda call). I think the problems is the 'scene' size and location is not correct. How can I make the size and starting (x, y) fo 'scene' to match the 'view' ones so the crosshair will be drew on the correct place.

Here are the new code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView;
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);

    view->setScene(scene);
    QMediaPlayer * player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QGraphicsVideoItem *item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    player->setVideoOutput(item);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path/to/tmp1.mp4"));
    // player->setMedia(QUrl("rtsp://10/0/8/100:8554/0"); // Live IP camera
    scene->addItem(item);
w.resize(640, 480);

    QObject::connect(scene, &QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged, [=](const QRectF &) { view->fitInView(item); });
    player->play();
    w.setCentralWidget(view);
    w.show();    

   // Draw a crosshair
   QPen p(Qt::red);
   qreal centerX, centerY;
   centerX = view->width() / 2;
   centerY = view->height() / 2;
   qreal halfLen = centerX / 2;
   (void)scene->addLine(halfLen, centerY, centerX + halfLen, centerY, p);
   (void)scene->addLine(centerX, centerY - 30, centerX, centerY + 30, p);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I added this line: scene->setSceneRect(view->x(), view->y(), view->width(), view->height); The crosshair is correct not but the Video became smaller again. Don't know why?

Comment: If you want geometry (line, rect, whatever) relative to the video item, you have to use coordinates resp. to that video item. If you add a line with view coordinates and do a fit-in afterwards, this will, of course, consider that line as well (and you get what you did but don't want).

Comment: The Qt doc. provides an intro to coordinate systems: [The Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system). This might help to understand the essence of your issues.

Comment: Thanks. After I read the documents, I got it figure out.